# Get full request URL in HTML::Mason

Tags: perl, mason

How do I get full request URI in a perl website using HTML::Mason? Or at least scheme used (http or https)?

Have tried $r->uri and $r->unparsed_uri but both return only path return the path component of the requested URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the environment variables HTTPS, SERVER_PORT, and REQUEST_URI. For example:

**mason_server.pl**:

```
use v5.38;
use HTTP::Server::Simple::Mason;

{
    package MyApp::Server;
    use base 'HTTP::Server::Simple::Mason';

    # Override 'mason_config' to provide the component root path
    sub mason_config {
        return ( comp_root => '/home/hakon/data/mason' );
    }
}
# Create and start the server listening on port 3000 using your subclass
my $server = MyApp::Server->new(3000);
$server->run();
```

And in the `comp_root` folder I have this file:

**index.html**:

```
% my $scheme = $ENV{HTTPS} eq 'on' || $ENV{SERVER_PORT} == 443 ? 'https' : 'http';
% my $request_uri = $ENV{REQUEST_URI};
Scheme: <% $scheme %><br>
Request URI: <% $request_uri %>
```

After starting the server, you can visit http://localhost:3000/ to check the result..